# Covariance between fitted values and residuals

Tags: statistics, regression, covariance

Given a linear regression model obtained by ordinary least squares, prove that the sample covariance between the fitted values and the residuals is zero.

Comment: Ordinary least squares assumes that there is covariance by definition. You can only show that the residuals are consistent with that assumption. You can't "prove" that the assumption is true.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you meant their dot product is zero. If so, let $\hat{y} = Hy$ where $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ (from OLS). Also, note that $H$ is idempotent, i.e. $H^2 = H.$ Then,
$$\hat y' . e = y'H(I - H)y = y'(H - H^2)y = y'(H - H)y = 0.$$